# Control+Mouse hover in IntelliJ not very useful

Tags: eclipse, intellij-idea, mouseover

I'm using IntelliJ 13.1 and when I hover over a variable with control pressed it shows a little popup right above the cursor. This popup has the class the variable is declared as with a hyperlink look, but when I click it, it just dissapears.

In Eclipse when I hover the mouse over a variable a little menu appears *[open declaration, open declared type]* and it it works just fine when clicking it. How can I get the same to work in IntelliJ?

Comment: What happens when you click the variable, as opposed to the popup?

Comment: It takes me to the declaration. I want to get to the declared type class. From what I know, the simplest way to do that is to control+click the variable, the in the definition line, control+click the class name. But this way I loose the position in the file that I was working on.

Comment: Last I checked, this functionality worked well on Android Studio. I'll have to check again. Are you using IntelliJ for Android development?

Comment: Yes, I'm using IntelliJ Community edition 13.1.3